# bash: How to intercept command line and do various actions based on the contents?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to know a solution to the following problem.

Problem: When I enter a number/string on command line, I should be able to interpret it in my own way, and do any action based on the contents of the string e.g. if it is a number then do action1, else do action 2, etc.

Example:

```
$ 85049  
[ This should do 'cd /dir1/dir2/../85049' ]
```

I cannot make an alias for this, as I can enter any big number.

Any ideas, how to achieve this functionality via bash?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `command_not_found_handle` function.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution

I don't think that's a very good idea though and would suggest that you rethink your original premise.